# Tornado blocking time

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

Tornado is regularly benchmarked at 1000req/s or above.

I have a blocking library that I would like to call (potentially in each request). If the library takes 30ms to complete and return, does that essentially give me:

```
1000 ms / 30 ms/req = 33.3 req/s
```

...as tornado's IOLoop will be blocked for basically the entire time?

If that is the case, is the multiprocessing approach in http://tornadogists.org/2185380/ the canonical method for dealing with blocking calls in tornado?